# Try to understand some weird symbols like ([]:_) in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I have difficulty to understand the following Haskell symbol `([]:_)`.

I come cross a Haskell function called transpose

```
transpose::[[Int]]->[[Int]]
transpose ([]:_) = []
transpose  x = (map head x):transpose(map tail x)
```

And I walk through a simple example.

```
transpose [[1,2],[3,4]]
=>[1,3]:transpose[2,4]
=>[1,3]:[2,4]:transpose[[],[]]
=>[1,3]:[2,4]:[]
=>[[1,3],[2,4]]
```

It seems to be make sense.

But If I pass `[[], [1]]` to the function, the output is still `[]`

```
transpose [[], [1]]
=>[]
```

Can anyone explain why transpose return `[]` if I pass `[[], [1]]`?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a symbol `([]:_)` is simply a short version of:

```
( [] : _ )
^  ^   ^
|  |   wildcard
|  empty list
list construct
```

The list construction is something like `( h :t )` with `h` the head (an element) and `t` the tail (either the remainder of the list, or the empty list). See [CONS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) for more information.

So it means: match a list with as head the empty list and as tail a *don't care*.

This makes sense, since a transpose is only well defined on rectangular structures. What do you expect the transpose of `[[],[1]]` should be.

The reason that this line is necessary, is because in the second (recursive) call, you use the `tail`s of all lists.

If you thus calculate the transpose of `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`, you will first take the recursive case: as `head`, you emit all the heads of all the lists, so `[1,4,7]`, and the recursion is done with the `tail`s of all the lists, so you call it with `transpose [[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]`.

In the second round (recursive call), you emit again the `head`s of the lists, so `[2,5,8]` and do the recursive call on the `tail`s: `[[3],[6],[9]]`. Next you emit again the `head`s `[3,6,9]`, and now the recursive call on the `tail`s is `transpose [[],[],[]]`. So a list of all empty lists. If the matrix condition hold however, it means we have finished. The pattern `( [] : _)` matches `[[],[],[]]` so it will emit the empty list `[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanations

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matrix! Your first row is empty, therefore the first condition is satisfied and returns empty list as defined.